# Overriding onTouch of Scrollview and call superclass method

Tags: java, android, events, scrollview, touch-event

I have overridden the onTouch-Event from my activity **and** the onTouch-Event of my scrollview. Because i've implemented a sliding menu animation.
But know the scrollview doesn't scoll. I tried to call the onTouch-Method (of scrollview) from the superclass but it doesn't works.

Can i first call the superclass method in the onTouch-Event (of Scrollview) and then call my own method (overridden onTouch of activity) for the sliding menu?

```
svMetaData.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)v;
            sv.onTouchEvent(event);
            return onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

The onTouch-Method behind the return statement is the overridden method (onTouch of activity).

Without overriding the onTouch-Event of the scrollview, the sliding animation only works when i touch the screen outside of the scrollview.

Comment: first call the superclass method in the onTouch-Event (of Scrollview) and then call your own method (overridden onTouch of activity) for the sliding menu. The scrolling of the scorllview lies on the touch event. So there will be a clash if you override.

Comment: Thanks but how can i call the superclass method? The exmaple above doesn't work. when i try to call super() i get the error: call to super must be first statement in contructor

Comment: why do you call return onTouchEvent(event); ?

Comment: return onTouchEvent(event) calls the overridden onTouch-method of my activity (it's for the sliding menu animation).

Comment: I have commented out everything (onTouch-Events). But the scrollview still doesn't work. Maybe there is another problem. Inside of the scrollview there is a linearlayout with a GridLayout. The scrollview is inside of a Gridlayout. I don't know why it doesn't work...